# JSONata sort / order by of an array

Tags: arrays, sorting, node-red, jsonata

I want to order an array. The JSONata expression below has an incoming array as follows.

```
[{"id":"Air-1a",
  "Controller":"ESP62",
 "Cntr-TaskNo":10,
 "Cntr-GPIO":13,
 "name":"Air",
 "valueName":"Humidity",
 "Sensor":"DHT22",
 (and many other key pairs)}, 
 {next object}, ...]
```

I then transform the array with the following JSONata expression:

```
payload.(
        { "Controller" : $.Controller,
          "Cntr-TaskNo": $.CntrDef.TaskNo,
          "Cntr-GPIO"  : $.CntrDef.GPIO,
          "name"       : $.name,
          "valueName"  : $.valueName,
          "Sensor"     : $.Sensor,
          "id"         : $.id
        }
)
```

But now I want to - in the same JSONata expression, sort on firstly the Controller, and then the GPIO. To tried with the Controller only first.

I tried:

```
payload.(
        { $sort("Controller",function($l, $r){$l.Controller > $r.Controller}) : $.Controller ,
          "Cntr-TaskNo": $.CntrDef.TaskNo,
          "Cntr-GPIO"  : $.CntrDef.GPIO,
          "name"       : $.name,
          "valueName"  : $.valueName,
          "Sensor"     : $.Sensor,
          "id"         : $.id
        }
)
```

As well as trying to add the sort function at the end with the ~> chaining command. I also tried the [order-by](https://docs.jsonata.org/control-operators#order-by) operator.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

//---------- 
The new flow with the changed 'ESP62' to '-' that does not work:

```
[{"id":"874b0c77.f87418","type":"inject","z":"6f27a311.d135bc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":200,"y":180,"wires":[["8c196590.c20638"]]},{"id":"8c196590.c20638","type":"change","z":"6f27a311.d135bc","name":"Dataset","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"[{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP62\",\"CntrTaskNo\":10,\"CntrGPIO\":13,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"111\",\"bbb\":\"222\",\"ccc\":\"333\"},{\"id\":\"Air-2a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP72\",\"CntrTaskNo\":11,\"CntrGPIO\":14,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"444\",\"bbb\":\"555\",\"ccc\":\"666\"},{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP62\",\"CntrTaskNo\":2,\"CntrGPIO\":9,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"777\",\"bbb\":\"888\",\"ccc\":\"999\"},{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"-\",\"CntrTaskNo\":10,\"CntrGPIO\":12,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"777\",\"bbb\":\"888\",\"ccc\":\"999\"}]","tot":"json"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":360,"y":180,"wires":[["13981162.14e28f"]]},{"id":"c8a256a5.a170c8","type":"debug","z":"6f27a311.d135bc","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":690,"y":180,"wires":[]},{"id":"13981162.14e28f","type":"change","z":"6f27a311.d135bc","name":"Jsonata $sort","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"($sort(payload,function($l , $r){$l.Controller > $r.Controller}) ; \t$sort(payload,function($l , $r){$l.CntrGPIO > $r.CntrGPIO}))","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":520,"y":180,"wires":[["c8a256a5.a170c8"]]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first sorting the dataset and afterward transform the already sorted array of objects. The transformation is trivial and you want to know how to sort, so I show below one possible solution. It uses an expression with two concatenated $sort functions.

Edited after a better understanding of the requirement.

I tested successfully a Node-RED flow using this expression in a change node:

```
($a := $sort(payload,function($l , $r){$l.Controller > $r.Controller}) ; $sort($a,function($l , $r){(($l.Controller = $r.Controller) and ($l.CntrGPIO > $r.CntrGPIO))}))
```

Flow (contain dataset set hardcoded):

```
[{"id":"a7814b7e.3adeb8","type":"tab","label":"Flow 4","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"8bf10833.c71748","type":"inject","z":"a7814b7e.3adeb8","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":140,"y":140,"wires":[["9e365564.edca08"]]},{"id":"9e365564.edca08","type":"change","z":"a7814b7e.3adeb8","name":"Dataset","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"[{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP62\",\"CntrTaskNo\":10,\"CntrGPIO\":13,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"111\",\"bbb\":\"222\",\"ccc\":\"333\"},{\"id\":\"Air-2a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP72\",\"CntrTaskNo\":11,\"CntrGPIO\":14,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"444\",\"bbb\":\"555\",\"ccc\":\"666\"},{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"ESP62\",\"CntrTaskNo\":2,\"CntrGPIO\":9,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"777\",\"bbb\":\"888\",\"ccc\":\"999\"},{\"id\":\"Air-1a\",\"Controller\":\"-\",\"CntrTaskNo\":10,\"CntrGPIO\":12,\"name\":\"Air\",\"valueName\":\"Humidity\",\"Sensor\":\"DHT22\",\"aaa\":\"777\",\"bbb\":\"888\",\"ccc\":\"999\"}]","tot":"json"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":300,"y":140,"wires":[["762f6421.074fec"]]},{"id":"f827bddb.c9acd","type":"debug","z":"a7814b7e.3adeb8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":630,"y":140,"wires":[]},{"id":"762f6421.074fec","type":"change","z":"a7814b7e.3adeb8","name":"Jsonata $sort","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"payload","pt":"msg","to":"($a := $sort(payload,function($l , $r){$l.Controller > $r.Controller}) ; $sort($a,function($l , $r){(($l.Controller = $r.Controller) and ($l.CntrGPIO > $r.CntrGPIO))}))","tot":"jsonata"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":460,"y":140,"wires":[["f827bddb.c9acd"]]}]
```

also tested in Jsonata exerciser: http://try.jsonata.org/S1IlT3y-E

Comment: Hi, I changed the 2nd ESP62 controller to '-' (I have such a data set), then it does not sort the Controller, instead, it has one ESP62, then the '-', then the other ESP62. Any ideas?

Comment: Your testing (value "-" in a property) unveiled the need to amend the expression. I edited the reply and hopefully, it is now working to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array using the following expression:

```
payload^(Controller, CntrDef.GPIO)
```

The order-by operator `^` will sort the array, first by increasing value of `Controller`, then by increasing value of `CntrGPIO`.  You can then transform each object within that array

```
payload^(Controller, CntrDef.GPIO).{
   "Controller" : Controller,
   "Cntr-TaskNo": CntrDef.TaskNo,
   "Cntr-GPIO"  : CntrDef.GPIO,
   "name"       : name,
   "valueName"  : valueName,
   "Sensor"     : Sensor,
   "id"         : id
}
```

Comment: A neat and elegant solution that shows the beauty of the power of JSONata.